# Rails 3.2 in production not showing any assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I've set up my server to use `RAILS_ENV=production` from my apache config, so that it uses the production database.

But now none of my assets are loading,

I have `group assets do` in my Gemfile.

And I have done,

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

It complains about my code and exits

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Ticket::UUIDHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
```

and show us the output.

And would you please show us your Ticket::UUIDHelper Modules/Classes?

Comment: i disabled that line to run it again, and it does stuff but still the assets won't show.